# Display billing_company when performing customer search in “Add New Sales Order” page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, action-filter, wordpress-hook

May I know how to display $user->billing_company upon results return when performing customer search in Sales Order form? Ideally am thinking of using filter/action hooks instead of modifying the core file in class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php

So far am able to search for customer based on the $user->billing_company, the results will show up on the editing order page, but not on the adding new order page ($user->billing_company is not displayed in real time upon typing and clicking on the searched result)

Images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4yfW.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjfEM.png

Modified code:

```
esc_html__( '[%4$s] %1$s (#%2$s &ndash; %3$s)', 'woocommerce' )
        $user->display_name,
        absint( $user->ID ),
        $user->user_email, $user->billing_company
```

Original code from class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php:

```
<?php
$user_string = '';
$user_id     = '';
if ( $order->get_user_id() ) {
    $user_id = absint( $order->get_user_id() );
    $user    = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    /* translators: 1: user display name 2: user ID 3: user email */
    $user_string = sprintf(
        esc_html__( '%1$s (#%2$s &ndash; %3$s)', 'woocommerce' ),
        $user->display_name,
        absint( $user->ID ),
        $user->user_email
    );
}
?>
<select class="wc-customer-search" id="customer_user" name="customer_user" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Guest', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" data-allow_clear="true">
    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user_id ); ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $user_string ); ?></option>
</select>
<!--/email_off-->
</p>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', $order ); ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following hooked function will allow you to display the billing company without modifying core files:

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'change_admin_single_order_heading3', 10, 3 );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'change_admin_single_order_heading3', 10, 3 );
function change_admin_single_order_heading3( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {
    global $pagenow, $theorder;

    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow === 'post.php' && isset($_GET['post']) && get_post_type($_GET['post']) === 'shop_order' )
    {
        if( $text === '%1$s (#%2$s &ndash; %3$s)' && $domain === 'woocommerce' && $theorder->get_user_id() > 0 ){
            // Get user meta billing company
            if( $billing_company = get_user_meta( $theorder->get_user_id(), 'billing_company', true ) ) {
                $translated = esc_html__( '['.$billing_company.'] %1$s (#%2$s &ndash; %3$s)', $domain );
            }
        }
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

> But you will not be able to display it when performing a search as the search choices are pulled with ajax…

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec , it now works in editing orders.

Is there a way to edit ajax files so that $billing_company will be displayed upon performing a search?

Comment: found the function to edit, `json_search_customers` inside `plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php`, thanks again!

Comment: @AllanTky Ok I will look at it… Thanks